# clr.AddReference('example_file') - unable to find assembly

Tags: python, .net, python-2.7, ironpython

I am trying to add reference to "example_file.dll" using AddReference('example_file') method from clr module:

```
>>>import clr
>>>clr.AddReference('example_file')
```

and in result I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'example_file'.

at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

All files are located in current working directory and sys.path looks like this:

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27', 'C
:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\
site-packages', 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\']
```

Additionally, in result of:

```
>>>clr.FindAssembly('example_file')
```

I get

```
u'example_file.dll
```

The problem arose from day to day. I am confused because it worked fine before - I don't know what could affect on this.
I am working with Windows 7 x64, python 2.73 and .Net framework 4

Comment: Have you tried using `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath` just to be explicit?

Comment: Is `example_file.dll` compiled against .NET 4? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259617/python-for-net-unable-to-find-assembly-error and http://sourceforge.net/p/pythonnet/bugs/18/ Has anything changed from "before"?

Comment: Everyone would probably agree and strongly suggest you moving away from the decade old and outdated Python2.7 and make a quantum leap into reality of Py3.7+.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

Answer (score 0):

Not really enought info here, but there are (at least) 2 things to think about:

1. That you are not having additional Python related environment variables, already set. For example using a vritual environment or having Python pointing to some other place. [Please check](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Using-Python.NET-with-Virtual-Environments) if `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` are set.
2. The the DLL you are trying to load have the same bit size as the Python interpreter. I.e . That if you have a 64-bit Python, you may need to load (but not always) a 64-bit DLL.
3. That the path specification is being read correctly, in your character set.
   `sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\SomeApi")`